# Передача value в TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, jquery

Вывожу данные из БД в `value` тега `<input type="textarea">` стилизованного плагином TinyMCE.
Проблема в том, что если value содержит не только текст а еще и теги то содержимое выводится вне `input` отдельными строками под `input`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В бд это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем вводится в БД текст тоже с помощью этого же плагина, но если использовать, например выравнивание текста по какому-либо краю происходит вышеописанная ошибка. Как это можно решить?

Comment: Отсключил TinyMCE и инпут ведет себя также

Comment: Переформулирую вопрос, можно ли использовать теги в атрибуте Value?

Comment: Вы правы! Только как теперь заставить TinyMCE генерировать не двойные кавыычи, а одинарные?

Comment: Что такое `type"textarea"`. Может быть `<textarea>`

Comment: input type="textarea", или это неверно?upd.  Неверно.

Comment: Я просто такого значения атрибута `type` нет в `html`. По крайней мере насколько я знаю. Есть тег `<textarea></textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в `input type="textarea"`, надо было заменить на `<textarea>`